# Uploaded files to Github LFS, after uploading ran into error compiling with Xcode with large files uploaded

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, git-lfs

I was having issues uploading files to GitHub remotely using LFS. Finally got it to work but when it was uploaded & I tried to compile my project on XCode, it showed the following errors:

> /Users/alexcarrabre/Desktop/Imbue/Pods/Target Support Files/MapboxNavigationNative/MapboxNavigationNative.xcconfig Ignoring build settings configuration file MapboxNavigationNative.xcconfig due to an error: String 'version https:' isn't a valid build setting assignment.
>
> /Users/alexcarrabre/Desktop/Imbue/Pods/Target Support Files/MapboxNavigationNative/MapboxNavigationNative.xcconfig:1: expected a ‘=’, but found h
>
> /Users/alexcarrabre/Desktop/Imbue/Pods/Target Support Files/GoogleAppMeasurement/GoogleAppMeasurement.xcconfig Ignoring build settings configuration file GoogleAppMeasurement.xcconfig due to an error: String 'version https:' isn't a valid build setting assignment.
>
> /Users/alexcarrabre/Desktop/Imbue/Pods/Target Support Files/GoogleAppMeasurement/GoogleAppMeasurement.xcconfig:1: expected a ‘=’, but found h

I then tried to re-install the cocoa-pods in file & ran into an error that said the following:

> alexcarrabre@alexs-mbp-3 Imbue % pod install
> Analyzing dependencies
> Downloading dependencies
> [!] The 'Pods-Imbue' target has transitive dependencies that include statically linked binaries: (/Users/alexcarrabre/Desktop/Imbue/Pods/Mapbox-iOS-SDK/dynamic/Mapbox.framework and /Users/alexcarrabre/Desktop/Imbue/Pods/MapboxNavigationNative/MapboxNavigationNative.framework)

I'm new to xcode/swift & would appreciate some help!

Comment: 1) What kind of files did you add to LFS? 2) how did you initialize lfs in your local repo? 3) what kind of issue did you have while you tried to push files to LFS and how did you fix them?

Comment: The issue you see is because LFS replaced actual files with links to files. This typically happens when LFS is not initialized in the local repo. And it can get worse if a person without LFS pushes changes to LFS-enabled repo

Comment: sorry, I forgot to say that I got it figured out. I just had to remove & reinstall my cocoa pods.

Comment: to answer you first question, it was just cocoa pods (mapbox sdk & mapbox navigation native sdk). I used the terminal and initialized it with "git lfs install" & then tracked the two pod files themselves. Then I migrated the info using this article (https://github.blog/2017-06-27-git-lfs-2-2-0-released/)